# npm ERR! code 1 when perforrming npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I have looked at the other posts concerning other people who had this or similar problems and those fixes don't seem to be working for me. When I run "npm install" I constantly get the line "npm ERR! code 1" Please help me.

```
**The error in the log state that**

8579 verbose npm  v7.11.1
8580 error code 1
8581 error path C:\Users\imm\Myproject\sms-react-web-client\node_modules\core-js-pure
8582 error command failed
8583 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
8584 error 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
8584 error operable program or batch file.
8585 verbose exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have installed Node.js. Try download and install it from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I installed the node v14.16.1-x64 most recomanded

Comment: What if you use 'node' command inside your terminal?

Comment: I get elcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.